# Integer Partition, with restriction

Tags: number-theory

I understand that integer partition has a rich history. There is one restriction on integer partition that I have not seen yet, which is you put a restriction on your number set (instead of all $\mathbb{Z}$, you may only use integers from $\mathbb{N}_k$).

$\mathbb{N}_k$ means the set of natural numbers up to k ({1,2,3,...,k})

Denote this by:
$P_{\mathbb{N}_k}(n)$

So
$P_{\mathbb{N}_1}(n) = 1 \forall n \epsilon \mathbb{N}$, namely n = 1 + 1 ...1 n times is the only way to sum to n with such a set.

My question is, for a fixed k, is there a closed form solution for $P_{\mathbb{N}_k}$ for some k? What about asymptotic behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: The set of natural numbers up to k {1, 2, 3,...k}. Fixed for clarity.

Comment: By the normal duality of Young diagrams, this is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts - that is, the number of positive solutions: $n=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_i$ with $n_{j}\leq n_{j+1}$ and $i\leq k$.

Comment: No, that is not correct, I am not making restrictions on the number of parts, but I am taking subsets of integers. When k = 7 and n = 9, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 has 9 parts, and should get counted, 8 + 1 does not, since 8 is not in N_7

Comment: Yes, I realize this, but the duality makes it the same count as restricting the number of parts and not restricting the size of the parts. (That's not true for general sets, but is true for $\mathbb N_k$.)

Comment: Ah, I understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generating function of $P_{N_k}(n)$ is
$$\prod_{j=1}^k\frac1{1-t^j}.$$
This is a rational functions, and for any given $k$ it can be expanded
as a partial fraction and a formula for $P_{N_k}(n)$ can be read off.

The dominant term comes from the term
$$\frac1{k!(1-t)^k}$$
in the partial fraction, so $P_{N_k}(n)\sim n^{k-1}/(k!(k-1)!)$.

Comment: This is the generating function of n in to at most k parts. This is not the same thing, I don't make any restrictions on the number of parts, just the number of numbers you are allowed to use. This looks polynomial for a static k, which is not true, in general it should be exponential. 

Suppose k = 7 and n = 9.
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
has 9 parts, but doesn't get counted in your generating function. But 8+1 gets counted, which is false, since 8 is not in N_k

Comment: I think you are wrong. $1+\cdots+1$ is counted as the $x^9$ term from $\frac{1}{1-x}$. @SpentDeath

Comment: More generally, for partitions into elements of some set $S$, the generating function is $\prod_{j\in S} \frac{1}{1-t^j}$

Comment: And when $S$ is finite (and relatively prime) then you get $$P_{S}(n)\sim \frac{n^{|S|-1}}{(|S|-1)!\prod_{s\in S} s}$$