# Total Collections of integers that sum to constant

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

For a range of positive integers $1 - S$, how many collections of $N$ integers are there that their sum is a constant $S$.

Example:

- Integers from $1$ to $100$
- Collections of $4$ integers
- Each collection should sum to $100$

eg collections in this case are [22, 23, 34, 21] and [19, 7, 31, 43].

How many different collections can there be?

As developer, I am implementing in code different algorithms to produce these collections and would like to know when an algorithm has found eg. 20% of them.

I am interested in an explanation of how this number can be achieved for a given range and sum.

Comment: are you allowed to repeat, i.e. is $97, 1, 1, 1$ a valid collection of $4$ integers to sum to $100$? Also do collections have to be non-intersecting, like if you chose $23,24,26,27$ as one collection, can you choose $22,24,26,28$ as the other one even thouh $\{24,26\}$ are present in both?

Comment: Yes, repeat and the order does not matter. I would be interested also to not repeat solution also, but mainly repeat.

Comment: If order does not matter, these are called *integer partitions*.  There is quite a bit of literature on counting them, specifically with [the restriction on size of summands](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437844/integer-partition-with-restriction) that you seem to have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are looking vor is named [partition function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) $P(n,k)$. It can be computed by recurrence relation
$$P(n,k)=P(n-k,k)+P(n-1,k-1),
$$
with
$P(n,k)=0$ for $n<k$, $P(n,0)=0$, and $P(n,n)=1$.

In particular, $P(100,4)=7153.$